# Is it possible to pass a xlwings object to multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, xlwings

My goal is to write a program in python that opens an Excel workbook and starts a macro. If the macro is not completed within a certain amount of time or if it encounters an error, the program should exit. This should not only terminate the process, but also close the Excel workbook. Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass the created Excel workbook to the multiprocessing process.

```
import pythoncom
import xlwings as xw
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def ExcelFunktionStarten(pfad, startanweisung, maxWartezeit):
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    xl_app = xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)
    t1 = mp.Process(target=ExcelRun, args=(pfad, startanweisung, xl_app, ))
    t1.start()
    vergangeneZeit = 0

    while t1.is_alive():
        if vergangeneZeit > maxWartezeit:
            t1.terminate()
            time.sleep(1)
            xl_app.quit()
            break

        else:
            print(vergangeneZeit, t1.is_alive())
            print(xl_app)
            vergangeneZeit += 1
            time.sleep(1)

 
def ExcelRun(pfad, startanweisung, xl_app):
    try:
        wb = xl_app.books.open(pfad)
        run_macro = wb.app.macro(startanweisung)
        run_macro()
        wb.save()
        wb.close()
        xl_app.quit()
    except:
        xl_app.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing your error, but I suspect it has to do with objects not being able to be pickled.

The pickle-module is used by multiprocessing behind the scenes to send your function arguments to other processes. This does not work for all objects, only for 'simple' objects. The xl_app object is definitely not simple (and I have no idea what your startanweisung is, I suspect it is a string with a VBA-macro). xl_app is a proxy to your actual Excel-application and it should be created on the process that actually runs your code.

If you move the definition of xl_app into the ExcelRun-function it should work, if you make xl_app a global variable it should work (though I do not know the larger context of your application to tell if any of this is a good idea)

If your goal is simply to run a command with a timeout you might want to look into the subprocess-module which supports such things.